# Is there a way to access last inserted row in table without auto-increment column?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using an AFTER INSERT trigger to retrieve information of recently updated row from table of one database, and store it in the table of another database. But, I am not sure how to retrieve last inserted row as the table has composite key(ClubID,CourtID) and none of them is auto-increment column. 
Here is my code for the trigger.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER if exists insert_court //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_court AFTER INSERT ON suchwow.Court
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE ckey2 INT;
   DECLARE ckey1 INT;
   DECLARE ckey3 INT;
   SELECT MAX(CourtKey) INTO @ckey2 from suchwow_analytical.Court;
   SELECT NEW.CourtID,NEW.ClubID INTO @ckey1,@ckey3 from suchwow.Court;
   INSERT INTO suchwow_analytical.Court(CourtKey,CourtID,FloorType,
   HourlyRate, ClubID,Street,City,State,Zipcode) 
   SELECT @ckey2+1,@ckey1,FloorType,HourlyRate,@ckey3,Street
  ,City,State,Zipcode from suchwow.Court c,suchwow.Club cl where c.clubID=cl.ClubID 
   and CourtID=ckey1 and cl.ClubID=ckey3;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting #1172 returned more than one row error. I am sure that NEW.CourtID and NEW.ClubID is the reason for it, but have no idea how to solve this problem. It would be of great help if you throw some insight as to how it can be solved.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing @ckey1,@ckey3 and directly using new.ClubID and new.CourtID solved my problem. Here is the solution for my question.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER if exists insert_court //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_court AFTER INSERT ON suchwow.Court
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE ckey2 INT;
   SELECT MAX(CourtKey) INTO @ckey2 from suchwow_analytical.Court;
   INSERT INTO suchwow_analytical.Court(CourtKey,CourtID,FloorType,HourlyRate,ClubID,
   Street,City,State,Zipcode) 
   SELECT @ckey2+1,CourtID,FloorType,HourlyRate,c.ClubID,Street,City,State,Zipcode
   from suchwow.Court c,suchwow.Club cl where c.clubID=cl.ClubID and
   CourtID=new.CourtID and cl.ClubID=new.ClubID;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```